# in c++ how do I return an array of objects from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

in c++ how do I return an array of objects from a function?

Comment: What does your book say?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By returning a std::vector.

Answer (score 6):

```
myobject *myfunc()
{
    return new myobject[10];
}
```

But beware - you are transferring ownership of the array to the caller, might be a cause for memory leaks.

EDIT: returning a pointer to an array is a lot faster than returning a std::vector. If you are going to use a std::vector (as others have written), you may prefer to do it like this:

```
void myfunc(std::vector<myobject> &result)
{
    result.resize(0);
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
       result.push_back(myobject());
}
```

Comment: Technically correct.  But this ignores the fact that this is horrible code. (edit: maybe it is objects)

Comment: @John What is so horrible about this code? What do object have to do with this?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: In reverse order:  OP asked specifically about an array of objects.  If you've been on SO for more than a few days, it should be clear why this is bad.  Leaking memory is not good, and this code is a breeding ground for memory leaks.

Comment: I did not conceal the drawbacks, didn't I? Nevertheless, I added a suggestion for using std::vector.

Comment: I'm on the verge of -1'ing this answer, for even suggesting `new[]` instead of `std::vector`, and then not returning the vector by value. NRVO exists for a reason, as do move-semantics in C++0x. Clean code always wins out. If, when you're *finished* with your program, you profile it and find returning vector's is a problem *then* feel free to mutilate the code.

Comment: @GMan: NRVO doesn't help much if the return value from the function isn't used in an initializer, and move semantics in C++0x are about as helpful as the fact that java.lang.Vector can be efficiently returned by garbage-collected reference, if what you're using is only standard C++. I think that C++ is a bit awkward here - all the options have downsides (return vector by value may be very inefficient; passing a vector breaks up expressions; returning a raw allocation is horrible; a template function taking an output iterator must be compiled in). We can't always act as though it isn't.

Comment: That said, I agree with the basic point, which is that the first suggestion should always be to return a vector by value, and consider the others only if that fails to perform adequately.

Comment: Don't blame me for C++ not having a good builtin mechanism for returning references to big data structures.